# Bind list object to path variable and get input values - Spring Form

Tags: jsp, jstl, modelattribute, spring-form

I am using **modelAttribute** to bind data to object and then store data using hibernate in J2EE application.

I have List phone; defined in model. How do I get multiple values from JSP page?

Steps in mind:
Step-1 : put one input box on jsp page.
Step-2 : put + button next to phone number input field. to add one more phone.

How do I implement that? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just did

```
<form:textarea id="phone1" placeholder="Number 1" class="form-control" path="phone"/>
<form:textarea id="phone2" placeholder="Number 2" class="form-control" path="phone"/>
<form:textarea id="phone3" placeholder="Number 3" class="form-control" path="phone"/>
<form:textarea id="phone4" placeholder="Number 4" class="form-control" path="phone"/>
```

And It worked.. Cheers.